# select an element using jquery attribute selector when attribute name is like "attr:attr"

Tags: jquery, svg, inkscape

For example, I have an svg path
`<path` ... `d="m 100.03365,51.648383 28.346,0 0,-28.346 -28.346,0 0,28.346" inkscape:label="figure_01"></path>`
All I want is to select him using attribute selector, like `$('path[inkscape:label*="figure"]')` which is doesn't work (and as I understand, it shouldn't because ":" is reserved for something more awesome).
Is there a way to bypass this without editing an svg itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the `:` symbol?

```
$('path[inkscape\\:label*="figure"]')
```